# How to use grep command inside Tcl script

Tags: tcl

How to run simple grep command in a tcl script and get output

```
grep B file1 > temp  # bash grep command need to execute inside tcl commad,
```

file1 looks like this:

```
1 2 3 6 180.00 B
1 2 3 6 F 
2 3 6 23 50.00 B 
2 3 6 23 F
```

these do not work

```
exec grep B file.txt > temp
child process exited abnormally


exec "grep B pes_test.com > temp1"
couldn't execute "grep -e B ./pes_test.com > temp1": no such file or directory

exec /bin/sh -c {grep -e B ; true} < pes_test.com > tmp1
works but do not gives output,
```

Comment: You will not get "child process exited abnormally" if the pattern you are looking for exists in the file. So it seems like you are just processing the wrong file; file.txt instead of file1.

Comment: Why drag an external program into it? It's trivial to open a file, and read lines and match a regular expression against each one in tcl.

Comment: okay thanks, @Shawn

Comment: You might also consider using the `fileutil` package from Tcllib. It has a `grep` command to do the heavy lifting.

Answer (score 1):

`exec` throws an error when the process returns non-zero. See [`exec`](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/exec.htm) and [the Tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/exec#1a39e854c66866d4b4567dcb8126b8f0914bdab191eea3a4812f3ca8d9d2bff3)

```
try {
    set result [exec grep $pattern $file]
} on error {e} {
    # typically, pattern not found
    set result ""
}
```

Ref: [`try` man page](http://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/try.htm)

Comment: It's _very_ irritating that the `CHILDSTATUS` error code puts the process ID before the exit code.